Remove Transactional Replication Manually or Via SSMS?
I am setting up transactional replication on my 2008R2 server to 2012 distribution server to 2012 Subscriber server. All the three servers are on FULL recovery mode. Log backup is taken every 15 minutes and full backup is taken daily everyday on all the three server databases used in replication. We want to use the subscriber as a reporting server. Publisher is our main OLTP database
For the rollback plan, I will be removing this replication and pointing the reporting server to the previous setup (Publisher)
So, I just want to know if I should be removing transactional replication via SSMS or manually? Are both approaches same?
I will be using these steps to delete transactional replication via SSMS:
On the publisher, right click on each publication, and delete the publication. That will prompt you to connect to the subscriber and remove the subscription components there. If you use SSMS as described, then it will fire off the necessary scripts to remove the replication metadata on the publisher, subscriber, and distributor.
I can also generate scripts from SSMS to remove replication as follows:
Right Click on Replication on Publisher - Generate scripts to Drop Replication
Right click on Replication on Distributor - Generate scripts to Drop Replication
Here, I am not sure if this order of running scripts is correct, like first generate 'Drop ALl' replication scripts on publisher and then generate 'Drop All' replication scripts on Distributor and execute them? Should I generate 'Drop all' scripts on Subscriber too after that?
I will be using this Microsoft documentation to remove transactional replication
Will deleting replication via SSMS delete replication completely?
